# When I make a new Certificate Authority with Google, why does it publish CA certificates over HTTP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, certificate-authority

Here's what I've done:

1. Create a new Certificate Authority with Google Cloud
2. Create certificate
3. View the certificate in Cloud Console
4. Under *Extensions* I can download the cert and the CA cert

Both of those links use http:// and now https:// which feels unsafe to me.

Why doesn't Google protect them with HTTPS URLs?

Comment: Are you saying the **download link** is using the HTTP scheme? If yes, your answer is wrong relative to your question. Otherwise, clarify your question with an example showing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because certificates are always signed, the use of HTTPS doesn't add anything to the publication of the certificate, and can sometimes prevent other services from using the certificate.

[Page 104 of RFC 5280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#page-104), which defines what an X.509 certificate should look like, answers this as follows:

> CAs SHOULD NOT include URIs that specify https, ldaps, or similar
> schemes in extensions. CAs that include an https URI in one of these
> extensions MUST ensure that the server's certificate can be validated
> without using the information that is pointed to by the URI. Relying
> parties that choose to validate the server's certificate when
> obtaining information pointed to by an https URI in the
> cRLDistributionPoints, authorityInfoAccess, or subjectInfoAccess
> extensions MUST be prepared for the possibility that this will result
> in unbounded recursion.

It also helps prevent circular dependencies. If a client needs to establish a HTTPS connection in order to build a chain which itself could be used to verify a HTTPS connection, they could get into an infinite loop. HTTPS is also unnecessary here since, as I mentioned above, CA certs downloaded from that URL must be signed by another trusted CA, so its integrity is preserved.